# Eclipse CDT not showing includes from docker Container

Tags: eclipse, docker, arm, cross-compiling, eclipse-cdt

I have setup eclipse cdt to build the binary using a docker container. The container is an Ubuntu image where simply is an arm-none-eabi cross toolchain installed. It is compiling fine and is finding all standard includes like "stdio.h" "stdint.h" etc. in the container while compiling. The only problem is, that eclipse is not showing those includes and I get a warning for every header that the files are not found and I cannot jump to the source files.

Do I have to do something special in the container like mounting the include paths to the host system because all I can find on the Internet are solutions where eclipse seems to automatically find the include paths inside the docker container?

Again, compiling works fine, only eclipse is not showing the include paths inside the container and giving me warnings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems like it is a bug in Eclipse...

You simply need to restart Eclipse and it shows the includes and the warnings are gone. Re-Indexing is not enough, it needs to be restarted...

Duh...